# erlang installation hipe issue on centos 6.7 - linux

Tags: linux, centos, erlang, ejabberd, hipe

I am trying to install ejabberd server. For that i am trying to install **ERL** depencies.

```
wget http://www.erlang.org/download/otp_src_18.1.tar.gz
tar -xzvf otp_src_18.1.tar.gz
cd otp_src_18.1
./configure
make
```

With above command give me below error in `make` i am not able to figured out how it would be solved. I have tried with `./configure --disabled-hipe` also but still i am facing issue with it.

```
=== Entering application hipe
make[3]: Entering directory `/etc/ejabberd_downloads/otp_src_18.1/lib/hipe/misc'
 ERLC   ../ebin/hipe_consttab.beam

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
Failed to create aux thread
/bin/sh: line 1:  6098 Aborted                 erlc -W +debug_info +warn_exported_vars +warn_missing_spec +warn_untyped_record -o../ebin hipe_consttab.erl
make[3]: *** [../ebin/hipe_consttab.beam] Error 134
make[3]: Leaving directory `/etc/ejabberd_downloads/otp_src_18.1/lib/hipe/misc'
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/etc/ejabberd_downloads/otp_src_18.1/lib/hipe'
make[1]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/etc/ejabberd_downloads/otp_src_18.1/lib'
make: *** [secondary_bootstrap_build] Error 2
```

**erl_crash.dump** top lines are as below:

```
=erl_crash_dump:0.3
Thu Nov 19 00:27:29 2015
Slogan: Failed to create aux thread
System version: Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.1] [source-2882b0c] [64-bit] [smp:53:24] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Compiled: Wed Sep 23 15:34:00 2015
Taints:
Atoms: 2005
Calling Thread: beam.smp
=scheduler:1
```

I am newbie with this one. Please help me.

Comment: The option to configure to disable hipe is `--disable-hipe` (without a `d` at the end) isn't it?

Comment: @EtanReisner , sorry that was typo mistake. `./configure --disable-hipe` than also i have tried one more time with this process with you have suggested but same error again..

Comment: I wouldn't expect hipe to be build if you ran with `--disable-hipe` that's why I'm surprised. I also wouldn't expect to see `[hipe]` in the `System version` line in the dump. What does `ulimit -a` say for the user running this?

Comment: `core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029731
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files   (-n) 1024
pipe size  (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues  (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority   (-r) 0
stack size    (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time      (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes   (-u) 1029731
virtual memory   (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks    (-x) unlimited`

Comment: A bit hard to read (updating the question would have been better) but that looks mostly reasonable. If you run `erlc -W +debug_info +warn_exported_vars +warn_missing_spec +warn_untyped_record -o../ebin hipe_consttab.erl` by hand (that seems to be the command that crashes) do you get any extra information about how/why it fails?